# count number of child elements in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I went through many answers to find how to count number of child elements in `Angular JS` but I didn't understood. Please have a look at my simple code and suggest me super **simple** method of counting no of childs.

I want count the total child under `<div id="myDiv">` and total `span` elements under `<div id="myDiv">`.

Here total `no of child = 5` and total `span elements = 3`

```
<html>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

        <button ng-click="countElem()">Count</button>
        <div id="myDiv">
            <span>child 1</span>
            <span>child 2</span>
            <span>child 3</span>
            <p>child 4</p>
            <p>child 5</p>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
                app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of querySelectorAll and get length on it

check the following snippet

```js
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.countElem = function() {
     var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
     var spanCount = div.querySelectorAll('span').length;
     var pCount = div.querySelectorAll('p').length;
     console.log("spanCount" + spanCount);

     console.log("pCount" + pCount);
   }
 });
```

```html
<html>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

  <button ng-click="countElem()">Count</button>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <span>child 1</span>
    <span>child 2</span>
    <span>child 3</span>
    <p>child 4</p>
    <p>child 5</p>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 Your HTML like this...

<div class="row"> 
  <div class="cols">col 1</div>
  <div class="cols">col 2</div>
  <div class="cols">col 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cols">col 1</div>
  <div class="cols">col 2</div>
</div>
```

You can use the below script :

```
angular.forEach(document.querySelectorAll('.row'), function(val, key){
 angular.element(val).removeClass('row');
angular.element(val).addClass('row'+angular.element(val).children().length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post, but this also works

```
var childNum = document.querySelector('#myDiv').childElementCount;
```

This also saves a DOM query